# Select Event id from event table where event start date and event end date are same

Tags: mysql

I have a `Event` table.

The attributes are:
 `event_id`,`event_name`,`start_date`,`end_date`.

I want to know all the id's where `start_date` and `end_date` are same.

How can I achieve this in mysql?

Comment: Do you mean: `WHERE start_date = end_date`?

Comment: Yes. but i will not give any input date.

SELECT
  event_id
FROM events
WHERE start_date = "2017-12-17"
AND end_date = "2017-12-20";

This I do not want

Comment: Do you want to find different events that share the same start- and endnote or just all the events where in itself the startdate is the same as the endnote?

Comment: " events that share the same start- and endnote "@MartinSchneider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find all events that share the same start- and enddate you have to join the table with itself.

```
SELECT
  e1.event_id,
  e2.event_id
FROM
  event e1 JOIN event e2 ON (e1.event_id < e2.event_id AND 
                             e1.start_date = e2.start_date AND 
                             e1.end_date = e2.end_date)
```

Will join the event table with itself if the start_date and end_date of two distinct events are the same. The condition `e1.event_id < e2.event_id` is to prevent that the same event is joined with itself AND that a pair of matching events is reported twice (for example [event1,event22] and [event22,event1])